# Deriving the CDF and PDF of the log normal distribution

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

We have that Y = $e^x$ and that X is a random variable with $X∼N(μ,σ^2)$. I want to obtain the density function $f_Y(y)$ of $Y$, by finding the cumulative distribution function $F_Y(y)$, and then differentiate. This is my work so far.

Suppose that $y\gt 0$.

$F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr(e^X\le y)=\Pr(X\le \ln y).$
Thus
$F_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\ln y}f(x)\,dx.$
I know I have to differentiate know,under the integral sign.
$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{y}f(\ln y).$ But how do I go from here to the formula of the PDF of the log normal distribution, which is
$$\frac{1}{y\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\, e^{\frac{-(log(y)-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} $$
Simply plugging in Y=$e^x$ wont do it. Where do $mu$ and $sigma$ come from?

Comment: The parameters come from the fact that $X$ is normal distributed as $X∼N(μ,σ^2)$

Comment: But where do X come in here? $ f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{y}f(\ln y)$

Comment: The equality is not true. Maybe you mean   $f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{y}f_X(\ln y)$. We have $F_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\ln y}f(x)\,dx$, where $f(x)$ is the pdf of the normal distributed variable $X$.

Comment: ()=∫ln−∞() is the CDF of the log normal distribution right? And we differentiate this to get the PDF?

Comment: Yes. But the starting point is to evaluate the distribution of $Y = e^X$.